# Azure service bus Connection aborted

Tags: sdk, azureservicebus

My application is deployed is deployed in azure cloud with Azure service bus configuration.
when i track log i can see many log related to connection aborted in info, warning and in error also.
com.azure.core.amqp.exception.AmqpException: org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.TransportException: connection aborted

Try to track this error, but not find any specific solution, why this log coming.

Answer (score 0):

- Here using the following way, I wasn't getting any exceptions while using azure service bus with spring boot JMS
- Now I am configuring the service bus in the `application.properties` file as below :

```
spring.jms.servicebus.connection-string=Endpoint=<Connection String>
spring.jms.servicebus.pricing-tier=<Price Tier>
```

- Now I have simple Rest api which just sends a message to the Azure service Bus

```
@RestController  
public class PostController {
    private static final String DESTINATION_NAME = "<queueName>";
    
    @Autowired  
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    @PostMapping("/messages")  
    public String postMessage(@RequestParam String message) {  
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(DESTINATION_NAME, new Test(message));  
     return message;  
    }
}
```

Here  `Test` is just a class with variable `name` and we are sending the object of class `Test`

output:
[image]

Comment: but this features available in premium tier only. I am using standard tier